# Incorrect JSONException

Tags: java, android, json, jsonexception

I'm trying to use JSON objects from the Guardian API.

This is the result from my call:

https://pastebin.com/wqggLEeZ

This is my code

```
JSONObject root = new JSONObject(jsonData);
JSONArray resultArray = root.getJSONObject("response").getJSONArray("results");

for(int i=0;i<resultArray.length();i++) {
    JSONObject resultElement = resultArray.getJSONObject(i);
    JSONObject blocksElement = resultElement.getJSONObject("blocks");
    JSONObject mainElement = blocksElement.getJSONObject("main");
    JSONArray elementsArray = mainElement.getJSONArray("elements");
    JSONObject elementsElement = elementsArray.getJSONObject(0);
    JSONArray assetsArray = elementsElement.getJSONArray("assets");
    JSONObject assetsElement = assetsArray.getJSONObject(0);

    String imageUrl = assetsElement.getString("file");
    String articleTitle = resultElement.getString("webTitle");

    news.add(new NewsList(articleTitle, imageUrl));
}
```

The code works fine except that it stops at 3 elements (i=2)

I tried replacing the imageUrl with "test" string in

```
news.add(new NewsList(articleTitle, imageUrl));
```

but it still stops at 3 elements.

But when I comment out the part where it finds the imageUrl the whole code works and gives me 10 results like it should do:

```
JSONObject root = new JSONObject(jsonData);
JSONArray resultArray = root.getJSONObject("response").getJSONArray("results");

for(int i=0;i<resultArray.length();i++){
    JSONObject resultElement = resultArray.getJSONObject(i);
    /*
    JSONObject blocksElement = resultElement.getJSONObject("blocks");
    JSONObject mainElement = blocksElement.getJSONObject("main");
    JSONArray elementsArray = mainElement.getJSONArray("elements");
    JSONObject elementsElement = elementsArray.getJSONObject(0);
    JSONArray assetsArray = elementsElement.getJSONArray("assets");
    JSONObject assetsElement = assetsArray.getJSONObject(0);
    String imageUrl = assetsElement.getString("file");
    */

    String articleTitle = resultElement.getString("webTitle");

    news.add(new NewsList(articleTitle, "test"));
}
```

I've looked around in Android monitor and it seems like it has a problem that says

> org.json.JSONException: No value for main

But that is not correct as the URL for the first 3 result is found without any problem, the problem only occurs after 3 iterations of the loop and I can't find any reason for why this is happening.

Comment: I've just copied code and response and run it, everything is alright on my side. All ten elements are parsed.

Comment: Not sure what is happening but the amount of "results" keep increasing as new articles are added to the guardian api :/ Guess ill wait for a bit and see what happens and maybe try it out other devices

Answer (score 1):

Use everywhere "opt" instead of "get', e.g.:

```
JSONObject assetsElement = assetsArray.optJSONObject(0);
String imageUrl = assetsElement.optString("file");
```

Comment: Doing that crashes the app

Comment: You need to check if objects returned after opt-methods are called are not null, e.g.: if (assetsElement != null) String imageUrl = assetsElement.optString("file");

Comment: If i check for null on blocksElement then the next statement is unable to access that blockElement even when i break in else statement

So i tried doing if(blocksElement==null) break; but that doesn't really make any difference..

Answer (score 1):

this is happening because of there is no field "main"  in the response at some position in the line

```
            JSONObject mainElement = blocksElement.getJSONObject("main");
```

so if at any of the position any of the fields are missing from the response, then after that position the code will not compile in JSON parsing.

sorry for bad english .

Comment: But that's not true, check the raw JSON file in the pastebin, it has the main element and should be able to find it

Comment: can you share the complete response of the API/WebServise which you are using  or the API/WebServise?